# How to give events on spark GridColumn

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a spark datagrid in which i have 2 columns editable. I want to handle events on the value set to this editable column in datagrid. I think i need 2 different event handlers to handle events in both the columns. But it shows me that gridItemEditSessionSave is not available for the GridColumn. Currently i have set the event to DataGrid. But only one handler is available for both the columns. It does not give me desired output. How to do this?

Comment: I do not understand your question.  You want to handle **WHAT** events on the value?  Are you talking about events dispatched by the renderer, by the DataGrid cell, or by the data object itself?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely only need one event handler to listen to both columns since many of the events dispatched by the datagrid class has a columnIndex and rowIndex to identify which cell in the datagrid dispatched the event.